# Having trouble loading info onto HTML from a JavaScipt function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an rpg card game but am having trouble loading the current "attributes " onto my HTML. I have 4 files, Index.html, player.js, playscreen.html, and gameplay.js where when you click on the play button the "gameEngine" is supposed to start and load up the attributes. The issue I am currently having is nothing is loading to my html, I linked my pages correctly but not even a console log will load.

Index.html:

```
<a href="./Interface/Playscreen.html" onclick="gameEngine.gameStart('Player')">Play Now!</a>
```

Player.js:

`

```
let player;

function Player(level, health, attack, speed, magic){
    this.level = level;
    this.health = health;
    this.attack = attack;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.magic = magic;
}
```

`

Playscreen.html:

```
<div class="attributes player"></div>
```

Gameplay.js:

```
let gameEngine = {
    gameStart: function(Player) {
        this.initPlayer(Player);
        this.loadEnemies();
    },
    initPlayer: function(){
        player = new Player(1, 100, 10, 10, 10);

        let loadStats = document.querySelector(".attributes");
        loadStats.innerHTML = '<p>Level'+player.level+'</p>';

     },
     loadEnemies: function(){

     },
     gameLoop: function(){

     }

}
```

Comment: Hyperlinks move you to another page, so when index.html changes into playscreen.html, the click event of the hyperlink is lost. Do not use hyperlinks as buttons if you do not have to. You probably have to move the call to gameStart() into a script in playscreen.html and run it on load. Keep in mind nothing you do inside index.html will affect things in playscreen with just the code shown, so might as well use a single file.

Comment: Thank you, it worked once I merged both files and then changed my hyperlink to a button!